# Laravel Passing Variables to Multiple Select Drop Down Array to string conversion Error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, forms, jquery-selectors

I am trying to push multiple selections from a drop down of specialties being displayed from my `$specialties` variable in an `@foreach` in a laravel application. I am able to capture 1 id and push it to the database, but multiple selections do not work. It only pushes one ID to the database. When I try name="specialties[]" as below I get error: Array to string conversion. How do I push my selection into an array using eloquent?

My form View:

```
 <div class="container">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <strong>Select Specialty:</strong>

        <select id="multiple-checkboxes2" multiple="multiple" name="specialties[]" value="specialties">
         @if($specialties)
             @foreach($specialties as $specialty)

             <option value=" {{$specialty->id}} ">{{$specialty->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        </div>
    </select>

      {!! Form::close() !!}

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#multiple-checkboxes2').multiselect();
     });
```

Client Store Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     //
     Client::create([    
           'specialties' => $request->specialties,     
     ] );  
     return redirect('/accounts');
}
```

Client display controller

```
public function display($id)
{    
  $specialties=Specialty::select( 'name', 'id')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get('id');
        return view('accounts/display', compact('accounts', 'specialties', )->withAccount($accounts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use array

```
<select id="multiple-checkboxes2" multiple="multiple" name="specialties[]">
     @if($specialties)
         @foreach($specialties as $specialty)
            <option value= "{{ $specialty->id }}">{{$specialty->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif      
</select>
```

Comment: If I do that, I get an array to string conversion error, which is a new error at least...any ideas? I think I need to create a second variable in my display controller that grabs the id of the specialties and passes it through to the value while the $specialty-name still serves as the selection

Comment: If I make the <option value= "" and make the select value "specialties", I can push the name of the specialty to the database, but clearly I would like the id.

Comment: I was able to capture the id and push it to the DB with $specialties=Specialty::select( 'name', 'id')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get('id');

but that does not push multiple selections to the database. When I include  name="specialties[]" I get error: array to string conversion